# How do you prove whether a simple unmeaningful code is computable or not?

Tags: c, computation-theory, formal-verification, formal-methods, computability

The characteristics of a computable problem are:

- **Complete** means that it covers all the cases;
- **Mechanistic** means that it is precise;
- **Deterministic** means that the same output will be provided if the same input is entered.

Correct me if I'm wrong, I found that through researches and don't fully knew what it actually means except for **deterministic**.

So, I'm trying to prove a simple code such as:

```c
int i = 0;
do{
    int j = 0;
    do{
        printf("Hello\n");
        j++;
    }while (j < n);
    printf("Hello\n");
    i++;
}while (i < n);
```

is computable.

I know how to show like it's **deterministic** since it's fairly obvious but I am not sure how to show that it's **mechanistic** or **complete**.

The **Complete** characteristic, from what I understand it's more of a "Is there any way that the code fail to be executed or returned as error?" such as opening a text file there's a chance that file doesn't exist because wrong file name entered or wrong location entered, etc.

But In the case of the snippet code above, how should I prove that it's complete?

As for the **Mechanistic** "whether 1 + 1 = 2 instead of 3?".

Same thing, for the case of snippet code above, how can I prove that it's precise since the code itself doesn't solve any problem it's just printing "hello" according to the n values? Which in this case n^2 + n number of "hello".

Comment: This seems like pretty pointless practice outside ["formal methods"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods), which might be what you are actually looking for.

Comment: You execute about n^2 printf calls. That is quite likely to cause you problems if n is large.

Comment: If n is a potato, the code will fail to compile, if n is floating point, it will be sometimes be hard to tell in advance how many iterations will actually happen. If n is unsigned or long (long), the code has the potential to loop indefinitely. So is it actually correct? Also "it's fairly obvious" is not a widely accepted format of proof.

Comment: Searching for the terms you used does not bring up anything too useful, you may have to go by the definitions (and/or explanations) you were provided and check whether those are satisfied.

Comment: I don't understand the question in the title: how can some code be unmeaningful and at the same time computable.  Do you understand what computable means?

Comment: The code prints `n*(n+1)` times the string `"Hello\n"` (if `n >= 1`, if `n == 0` it prints `"Hello\n"` twice).  What does _unmeaningful_ to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up a few things.

Firstly, you provided a piece of code and asked how to prove that it is computable. But that doesn't make any sense - a piece of code cannot be computable or not computable.

A (mathematical) *set* can be computable or not computable. And based on that, everything else that is also a set: for example a *language* (which is a set of strings), a *decision problem* (which is a set of accepted inputs) or a *function* (which is a set of key-value pairs).

Secondly, the "characteristics"  you mention don't define computable problems. I don't know where you got them from, but they are at best a very informal description of some aspects of an *algorithm* for solving a computable problem. So I think you are not talking about computable problems, but about *algorithms*. But given that your characteristics are informal, you can't *prove* them.

So here are some slightly more precise (but still not formal) statements that may be helpful:

- A problem is *computable* iff there exists an algorithm that solves it.
- An algorithm solves a problem iff

  - it can be expressed within a standard model of computation (e.g. a Turing Machine or a standard programming language);
  - it is *sound* with respect to the problem: any answer produced by the algorithm belongs to the answer set of the problem;
  - it is *complete* with respect to the problem: any element of the answer set of the problem is produced by the algorithm;
  - the algorithm halts on all inputs.

Now these are characteristics that are precise enough that you can actually use them for proving that a problem is computable, or that an algorithm solves a particular problem.